# Trapped in obsidian and going to be executed in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend is holding me hostage on a minecraft world we made. All I have is dirt, wood, a stick, and a sapling. I'm in a one by one giant pillar and I might be executed soon and I need a way out. I'm on bedrock on tablet. It's just me and my friend. Does anyone know a way out?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you need to break the obsidian?

Comment: I suspect convincing your friend not to play such tricks on you would be a better idea.

Comment: Nicely ask them or otherwise threaten them to let you out. Alternatively, break the obsidians by hand and get out of there.

Comment: Also, if your spawn is not in that pillar, let them execute you ASAP so you would respawn outside

Answer (score 4):

Although it might be on the slow side, obsidian is breakable by hand (250s per block).

Alternatively, try planting the sampling (then build up to avoid suffocation damage), see if that's enough wood to get you out from the top? (Crafting slabs, and placing them with air gaps in between will grant you more height with the limited resources).